# How do I continuously run and host Node.js script on Heroku?

Tags: web-hosting, heroku

I currently want to deploy a website ranking API, and for that I need a web crawler. The thing is I want to keep the web crawler running 24/7 so it can continuously update the websites. However, with services like Heroku, after one hour the server stops. So all my crawling progress is gone and I have to recrawl. How do I host a Node.js script that is always alive on Heroku. If it is not possible, what else can I do?

Comment: Are you open to the obvious suggestion of finding a different host that supports 24/7 operation of a crawler?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller What options are there, you think I did not already search?

Comment: If you get a virtual private server (VPS) you have complete control over what is running on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either a VPS (Virtual Private Server) or perhaps a more powerful Dedicated Server.

You will then have root access and create cron jobs and processes that generally aren't permitted on shared hosting.

On shared hosting if something goes wrong, it can affect all customers on that machine.  With your own server you are responsible for it all and any rogue script or excessive load only affects you.